# Is it possible to get gcc to ignore unknown -W... command line options?

Tags: gcc, command-line-arguments

I have a build configuration that has some "-Wno" options meant to cover both 'gcc' and 'clang'. The problem is that gcc doesn't recognize some of the clang specific ones and fails to compile because of it.

Example of the error:

```
 error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign"
```

Is there a way to tell gcc to ignore command line options that it doesn't recognize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default for gcc >= 4.4, see https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html

Prior to gcc 4.4, this is not possible to achieve. The suggestion above on -Wno-error=unknown-warning is incorrect, and is possibly a result of misreading the gcc manual (where "unknown-warning" is used as an example for a warning that gcc does not recognize).

Comment: I don't have the moment to re-test right now, but the "-Wno-error=unknown-warning" solution had been working for me at the time that I posted it.

Comment: This still print the warning if something else is found. Seems like it cannot be helped.

Comment: using gcc (GCC) 7.3.0, with -Werror, it gives an error for unrecognized warning silencings. For example cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-class-memaccess’ [-Werror]

Answer (score -1):

It turns out there is a warning `unknown-warning` that with `-Werror` becomes an error.

This can be disabled with:

```
-Wno-error=unknown-warning
```

Comment: That doesn't work with arm-linux-androideabi-g++ v4.6.3 which still gives "error: unrecognized option '--dynamic-linker'"

Comment: it may only work for items passed through the compiler. If the front end passes the options to the linker, the linker might be the one complaining.

Comment: echo 'int main(){return 42;}' | gcc -x c -Waaa -Wno-error=unknown-warning - 

does not work for me.

Comment: On gcc 4.1 it just gives `unrecognized command line option "-Wno-error=unknown-warning"` :/

Comment: Indeed, this is incorrect. gcc 4.4 also gives `cc1: error: -Werror=unknown-warning: No option -Wunknown-warning`.